# According to the Church of God (Cleveland), are children sin-free?

Tags: sin, children, pentecostalism

I work with children in a day care that is part of the [Church of God](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_of_God_(Cleveland,_Tennessee)).  Naturally, all of the employees except me are of the Church of God, which is fine by me.  I am non-denom.  I find it curious that one of my co-workers stated that the children in my toddlers and twos class are "sin-free."  I feel a bit odd asking anyone there about it since they are all COG.  I don't understand how a human born of Adam and fallen short of the glory of God could be free from sin.  I understand there is an age of accountability around 12 or 13, but does the COG teach that young children are "sin-free"?

Comment: You can easily answer that by looking for children that don't sin... I'm surprised your co-worker can conclude that when working with children.

Comment: I agree.  No one teaches them to scream NO! or hit each other or take toys and watch for a reaction just for spite.  It's all pre-programmed.

Comment: Yours is a perfectly good question if put this way: How does the COG explain that young children are "sin-free"? If you revise your question thus, it can be taken off hold.

Comment: What does the CoG teach regarding "original sin"?  Per WIKIPEDIA: "Original Sin of Depravity- the church believes that original sin or depravity is that corruption of the nature of all the offsprings of Adam by reason of which everyone is very far gone from original righteousness or the pure state of our first parents at the time of their creation, is averse to God, is without spiritual life and inclined to evil, and that it continues to exist with the new life of the regenerate until eradicated by the baptism of the Holy Spirit."  Therefore, they are not "sin free".

Comment: Per [CoG Site](http://www.churchofgod.org/resolutions/children-and-youth-1998) "All children and youth are a heritage of the Lord (Psalm 127:3, NKJV), to be cherished, protected, defended, redeemed, and discipled."  Nothing about children being "sin free".

Answer (score 1):

The Church of God by Faith (not sure if there is a distinction like there is between Churches of Christ) does *officially* hold to original sin. However, many individual members of all denominations have *'s on that doctrine, if not outright reject it. One of the *'s being  an age of accountability that you mentioned, before which salvation is given without formal repentance, baptism, and so on depending on denomination. For example, many hold that an aborted baby would go to heaven irrespective of the guilt they believe comes by way of original sin.

(As an addition, the doctrine of original sin doesn't come from passages about or addressing the theology of the actual original sin of Adam and Eve. Rather it comes from passages that are poetic in form and are in the context of repenting in extremely serious circumstances. I.E. Psalm 51, where David has been convicted of adultery and murder and is about to face strong consequences. As such, the doctrine of guilt at birth is justifiably debated among believers).